# Subsonic out of memory exception

Tags: subsonic, timeout

I am currently using Subsonic 2.1 and I am receiving an error message when I attempt to use Subsonic to pull back large amounts of data (@ 140,000 records) from an sql database table. Is there an configuration setting that I need to change in order to allocated more memory for my application to complete the task?

Answer (score 0):

The question is - why are you opening 140,000 records?
If you are data mining,reporting or doing big data transfers, I would suggest that you don't use Subsonic for this, but use a better suited tool.

Comment: We were using subsonic because of its performance when dealing with collections and look ups. I was hoping that there would be a configuration that I could add to the config file or a setting I could change in the tables class file for that particular table that would allow it to work with large amounts of data as it does smaller sets.

Comment: If you are using for it lookups, you should filter it for the data you require. Also you look at the lazyLoad setting, as this will only load the foreign object when you access it such as
  Order and OrderDetails, OrderDetails will load when you access the method/property from the Order object.

Comment: The problem with that being is that I need the order information first which is where the bulk of the data resides.

Comment: Two suggestions,
 try the paged method and page the data or use a datareader and load the object with the datarow each time.
If you use the same object to hold the data, I think you will not run into the memory problems.
 I am not sure what you are trying to do, are you doing batch update? Is why not execute a query.

Comment: The reason i am pulling back this much information so we can batch all the orders from a certain group together for cost effective savigns with our mailing vendor.

Comment: Yes, but you can still page it to get all the records, and not have the memory issue.

Comment: Seems that you are exporting the data, why not use DTS or reporting services instead.